# Split string twice and adding to dictionary

Tags: c#, regex

foreach (string x in Value.Split('|'))
    {
        var y = x.Split(',');

```
    if (y.Length == 1)
        Options.Add(y[0], y[0]);
    else if (y.Length == 2)
        Options.Add(y[0], y[1]);
}
```

It should process strings like:

- `b|123|1,op|999`
- `1|2|3|4`

... and add them to a `Dictionary<string, string>`. It splits the string in the character `|`. Then it splits it again in the character `,`. If there is one element, it adds to a dictionary the same key and value. If there are two elements in the array, then it adds to the dictionary an element when the key is the first element in the array, and the value is the second element in the array.

For example, in the string:

```
b|123|1,op|999
```

The dictionary should look like:

```
Key | Value
-----------
b   | b
123 | 123
1   | op
999 | 999
```

It's working, but I'm looking for a more clean way to speed it up using regex or something... The program is that I do not know regex... Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to speed it up, is it slow? Don't optimise prematurely, it looks find to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster using regex?

Comment: Regex is not faster than String.Split().  Simple is better.

Comment: No it wouldn't. There're ways to do it much faster, but these are not related to regex.

Comment: I am extremely weak in C#. Can you do split *without* creating new strings? Manually - traverse char by char and implement the split manually - it'll be more complex and error prone, but faster i believe.

Comment: Yes, you can scan the string without splitting. See my edit below.

Comment: @Pavel: Regex was just an (wrong) example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression like this:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("b|123|1,op|999", "([^|,]+),([^|,]+)|([^|,]+)")) {
   string value3 = m.Groups[3].Value;
   if (value3.Length > 0) {
      Options.Add(value3, value3);
   } else {
      Options.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
   }
}
```

If you measure the performance, I am pretty sure that the regular expression version is slower.

Edit:
Here is a technique that scans the string for separators, and only creates the substrings that are used in the dictionary:

```
string input = "b|123|1,op|999";
int key = 0;
int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
   switch (input[i]) {
      case ',':
         value = i + 1;
         break;
      case '|':
        Options.Add(input.Substring(key, key == value ? i - key : value - key - 1), input.Substring(value, i - value));
        key = i + 1;
        value = i + 1;
        break;
   }
}
Options.Add(input.Substring(key, key == value ? input.Length - key : value - key - 1), input.Substring(value));
```

Comment: @Alon: Yes. It's about twice as fast. (I measured the regular expression version also, and it's about ten times slower.)